# How can I write a JSONObject to a firebase database node

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently trying to migrate an app to firebase from a SQLDatabase. I have done all the work to convert the database to a JSONObject. Is there a way I can just fill a user node in firebase with this object?

I tried to write the JSONObject with

```
database.getReference("/" + user.getUid() + "/").setValue(jsonObject);
```

this returns the error

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class org.json.JSONObject
```

I'm trying to avoid breaking apart the object and posting individual values seperatly because this could be error prone and I can't risk corrupting data with a messed up loop... Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the json into an object using `ObjectMapper`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
User user = mapper.readValue(jsonObject.toString(), User.class);
```

https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html

Then you can use the instance of the class `User` in `setValue()`:

```
database.getReference("/" + user.getUid() + "/").setValue(user);
```

From the docs:

> In addition, you can set instances of your own class into this location, provided they satisfy the following constraints:
>
> The class must have a default constructor that takes no arguments
>
> The class must define public getters for the properties to be assigned. Properties without a public getter will be set to their default value when an instance is deserialized

Comment: I'm trying to implement the class but I'm using gradle, could you please advise me as how to do this? I got a jar from the maven repositories and put it in my libs folder but it is not compiling.

Comment: Use gson instead https://github.com/google/gson `dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}`

Comment: Then you can do `Gson gson = new Gson(); User user = gson.fromJson(jsonObject, User.class);`